# Laurent expansion at infinity for a weakly modular function with respect to a congruence subgroups

Tags: analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, arithmetic-geometry

Let $\Gamma\subset \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb Z)$ be a congruence subgroup and  $h$ the fan width of $\Gamma$ (i.e;  the minimum $h>0$ such that $\left(%
\begin{array}{cc}
 1  &  h \\
 0  & 1 \\
\end{array}%
\right)\in\Gamma.)$ and let $f$ be a weakly modular function with
respect to $\Gamma.$
Let

$$q_h:\mathcal{H}\longrightarrow D^*=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\;:\; 0<|z|<1\}\;\;\; z \longmapsto e^{\frac{2\pi iz}{h}}$$
In this [note](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masmat/files/teaching/fall15/modforms.pdf) (page 29) I find this statement :"Define $g$ by $g = f\circ q^{-1}_{h}$. That is, $g(q_h) = f(z).$ Although $q_h$ is not invertible, the above definition makes sense, and $g$ has a Laurent expansion"

Can someone explain to me why the definition $g = f\circ q^{-1}_{h}$ makes sense although $q_h$ not invertible ?

Can we take $g(q)=f\left(\frac{h\log(q)}{2\pi i }\right)$ ?

Thanks.

Comment: You mean $\begin{pmatrix}1&h\\0&1\end{pmatrix} \in \Gamma$, right?

Comment: @Ted,yes exactly, I'll edit this. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula $$g(q) = f\left(\frac{h \log(q)}{2 \pi i}\right)$$ makes sense despite the multi-valuedness of the $\log$ function, because the values of $\log$ are determined up to an integer multiple of $2 \pi i$.  Choosing a different value of $\log(q)$ will therefore change the argument of $f$ by an integer multiple of $h$.  But $f(z+h) = f(z)$ by the assumption that $h$ is the fan width.  So there is no ambiguity in the definition of $g$.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.